# Is the structure, "adj. + v. + adj.", grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Actually, I'm titling the manuscript of my academic research. I wonder if I use something like "Temporal Meets Spatial: XXXXXX" or "Static Meets Dynamic: XXXXXXX" to be the title, will it confuse the readers or make them uncomfortable in grammar?

Comment: You're personifying the abstractions with the verb "meets". That's grammatical and should cause no confusion for the overwhelming majority of readers, though some might wonder what exactly you mean by "meets".

Comment: @TimR Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just using adjectives like that is a non-starter. **The X Meets the Y**, might work. For example: Enter interactive content in email campaigns—where **the static meets the dynamic**, creating an engaging user experience that captivates and converts. This isn’t just another trend; it’s a fundamental shift in how businesses communicate with their audience. https://www.winsavvy.com/harnessing-the-power-of-interactive-content/

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your insights! It's also quite helpful.

Comment: It really might depend on that XXXX, What field is it in?

Comment: For example, “Temporal Meets Spatial: Recognizing Evolving Structures in Ecosystems” where I’d like to describe a new method for constructing time-varying complex networks in ecosystems.

Comment: Lambie's comment is nonsense - there's nothing wrong with using adjectives because ultimately the whole thing is an adjective, even though you're using it as a title. Further, 'temporal' and 'spatial' describe abstract things so it doesn't make any more sense to add definite articles - you cannot sum up *all* that is related to space and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine because the entire construction is an adjective phrase.

I've heard "*X meets Y*" constructions called 'comparative descriptions' or 'analogy-based descriptions'. But whatever they are called, it doesn't matter if they use nouns or adjectives - the complete phrase is an adjective because it describes something.

For example, it's common in treatments and pitches for TV shows and movies to describe something as "*[Name of one show] meets [name of another show]*". Two nouns (the names of other shows) are being used within the comparative description, but ultimately the phrase is used as an adjective to describe the new show that is being pitched.

So it doesn't matter what the individual words are so long as the two things being compared are comparable, and in the case of them being phrases have their own internal grammatical sense.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this concept! It's extremely helpful.

Comment: Adjective phrases don't have verbs like **meets**.

Comment: @TimR Your comment is ill-thought-out, Tim. Where "ill-thought-out" is an adjective phrase to describe your comment, and 'thought' is a verb; past simple and past participle of think.

Comment: **thought-out** is an adjective, not a verb there, albeit forned from the past-participle. You're saying, if I understood you correctly, that "Temporal Meets Spatial" is an adjective phrase.  "Meets" is a 3rd-person singular present-tense verb.

Comment: @TimR But you said adjective phrases can't contain verbs? Were you wrong then, or are you wrong now?

Comment: It isn't a verb.

Comment: @TimR *To think* is a verb.

Comment: But it isn't "to think". It is the adjective "thought-out". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thought-out#:~:text=%3A%20produced%20or%20arrived%20at%20through,a%20thought%2Dout%20plan

Comment: @TimR Actually I said "*ill-thought-out*", but it doesn't matter, they are both adjective phrases and 'thought' is absolutely a verb. It's functioning as a verb within the phrase, because it is telling you that the thought process has been carried out (badly, in your case). But the whole thing is acting as an adjective, of course. And yes, I'm saying "[x] meets [y]" is an adjective phrase. It describes things. For example, if you wrote your life story, I'd add a quote on the back that said "*It's John Wick meets Titanic!* because it's brainless and it's going down.